# Outlook MAPI store provider. Managed?

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

Is it possible to create MANAGED (.NET) Outlook MAPI store provider? How?

I'm a complete novice in Outlook world, but don't wont to fiddle with all that COM droppings.

Comment: hi aloneguid! Since you mentioned below that you've managed to get it working (albeit in c++) would you mind sharing how did you add your store provider to outlook? See my email in the profile. Thanks!

Comment: Would really appreciate any code examples or pointers to how I could write a lightweight provider to allow a legacy application to send an email to my custom mapi provider! (Want to be able to convert this request into a different message format)

Answer (score 0):

I too have wondered this.  From digging around and the [rule of not using .Net with MAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stephen_griffin/mapi-and-net), I do not think it is possible to accomplish.

You might be able to bend C++/CLR to get close close, but it is probably pretty ugly code.  Doing it in unmanaged C++ is probably the most straight forward and easiest.

Comment: We finally ended up with a very thin store provider written in C++ which calls managed process for almost everything via IPC.